# Best way for using async/await in EntityframeworkCore

Tags: c#, async-await, entity-framework-core

for using async/await in entityframeworkcore i use this way,
I want to know if my method is correct or not? Is there a better way?

```
public async Task<T> Create(T entity)
        {
            using (var db = new myDbContext())
            {
                var created = await db.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return created.Entity;
            }
        }

public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll()
        {
            using (var db = new myDbContext())
            {
                var items = await db.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
                return items;
            }
        }
```

and for using this method:

```
IDataService<Stock> Data = new GenericDataService<Stock>();

            Data.Create(new Stock { id = 2, name = "ok" }).Wait();
            foreach (var item in Data.GetAll().Result)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(item.name);
            }
```

Comment: I don't want to speak to correctness or the one best way, but I can say for sure that blocking on an async call (`Data.GetAll().Result`)  is bad. At best it defeats the purpose of having async code, at worst it deadlocks.

Comment: @Crowcoder So how should I call it?

Comment: `await` it as you have done in the other methods.

Comment: Also in an async Task/void so you can await the call.

Comment: According to the notes for `AddAsync` you would only use `AddAsync` if one of the fields uses special value generators that need to access the database async. In default cases they recommend to use `Add` instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.addasync?view=efcore-3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid sync-over-async `.Result` for not completed `Task` because it's nonsense in [Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async). It may cause deadlocks and makes the nature of `async` useless.

In case of synchronous caller method you may at least do this

```cs
IProgress<string> status = new Progress<string>(s => MessageBox.Show(s));

Task.Run(async () =>
{
    Stock entity = await Data.Create(new Stock { id = 2, name = "ok" });
    foreach (var item in await Data.GetAll())
    {
        status.Report(item.name);
    }
});
```

`Progress` here just executes callback in the UI thread. Avoid updating UI from pooled threads.

But it's not the only way to solve it.

If you're in Event handler, just make it `async` and simply use `await` inline without `Task.Run()` and callback.

Also I suggest to rename the methods to `CreateAsync` and `GetAllAsync`.